# kubectl label - How to label "spec : template : metadata : labels"

Tags: kubernetes

Ho do you set the following label in an already applied deployment?

```
kubectl label deployments my-deployment-v1 app=my-deployment
```

Is setting:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-v1
  labels:
    app: my-deployment
```

And I need, the following for a service to find it:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-v1
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-deployment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) your resource like this:

```
kubectl patch deployments/my-deployment-v1 \
-p '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"my-deployment"}}}}}'
```